# SSRS, Split Value Field before passing to main query

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working on a SSRS report.

I have a parameter. the **Value Field** gives me IDs separated by delimiters, After user selection, I want the selected value field to be processed and put it in a variable then pass it to the main query to display the result. Please tell me how can I do that, do I need to use script, if yes, how can I? an early reply is appreciated. This is live production issue, so need to fix ASAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a single value with IDs separated by delimiters. Instead, set your parameter to accept multiple values and amend your query accordingly.